# Why does this amplifier not work past a given Vcc?

Tags: transistors, amplifier, switches, bjt

This circuit works well enough in simulation, I've built it and I can't get the final stage to put more than around 16V across the load.

The last stage itself is performing like a voltage follower in that the voltage to this stage seems to cap off at around 17V, however when common emitter stages are in isolation they turn on and (almost) 28V can be switched.

Dropping the final stage's base resistor values actually worsens the problem - i'm stumped

The 300R simulates the AC equivalent load i'm working with, which is a piezo pump

[image: pump driver]

Comment: Are the signals at X1 and X2 exactly 180 degrees out of phase?

Comment: Also, you have your Q3 and Q4 hooked up in reverse from how you'd normally  build this circuit, but I don't think that's the cause of the problem you're asking about.

Comment: You said the 300ohm resistor is how you modeled the actual load. Did you try to test the actual circuit with a 300ohm power resistor? I suspect that a piezo pump behaves quite differently than a simple 300ohm resistor and this may account for the different circuit behavior.

Comment: How do Q3 & Q4 ever turn on in your circuit? Their B-E junctions can never be forward-biased. You appear to have C and E reversed.

Comment: @The Photon - yes they are 180 degree out of phase
- yes I know, the final stage is effectively a current amplifier (emitter follower), this way has less chance of bleed through

Comment: @LorenzoDonati - you are right that the piezo load isn't simply a 300 resistance, however in the sim it is and works fine, i've tested with different loads with no change in behavior

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your circuit is the 2N3906 transistors are wired backwards. In this configuration they have very low gain, but the real problem is that reverse bias between the Base and Emitter exceeds the breakdown voltage, which is *not* modeled in the simulator.

According to its [datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/2N3906-D.PDF) the 2N3906 has a minimum Emitter−Base breakdown voltage of 5V, which must not be exceeded. In practice it acts like a Zener diode with a typical breakdown voltage of ~7.5V. In your circuit this clamps the voltage at the lower end of R1/R10 to ~7.5V, loading down the driver stage and reducing output voltage. Using a lower value Base resistor makes it worse because it pulls more current through R2/R5 which lowers the drive voltage even more.

Fixing the problem is simple, just swap the Collector and Emitter of Q3/Q4. For the future, remember that simulation is only as good as the models used, and most models do not simulate accurately when the device is operated outside its specifications.

Comment: You are correct! Thanks for your help and the advice